# Single Table Inheritance with Devise Invitable accept url not using child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I have the following structure

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :invitable
end

class Administrator < User
end
```

When I invite an administrator, the link to the accept the invitation goes to `/users/invitation/accept`, what I need is `/administrators/invitation/accept`.

I have the views overridden for administrators and devise, so I have `app/views/administrators/invitable/edit.html.erb`. I'm trying to add fields to this page that aren't related to a user.

Is there a way to overwrite that without having to override the entire email sending process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create the Inevitable views using

```
rails generate devise_invitable:views
```

The generated mailer file in:

```
app/views/devise/mailer/invitation_instructions.html.erb
```

Edit it as following:

```
<p><%= t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.hello", email: @resource.email) %></p>

<p><%= t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.someone_invited_you", url: root_url) %></p>

<%
  url_part = if @resource.is_a?(Admininstrator)
               'administrators'
             else
               @resource.class.to_s.underscore.pluralize
             end

%>
<p><%= link_to t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.accept"),
               "http://#{MAILER_HOST}/#{url_part}/invitation/accept?invitation_token=#{@token}" %></p>

<p><%= t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.ignore").html_safe %></p>
```

NOTE: The route sub_part you see, is mainly generated by the way you override device routes.

i.e. check if

```
rake routes | grep -i invitation
```

Has a path

```
 new_administrator_invitation GET      /administrators/invitation/new(.:format)                                 /administrators/invitations#new
```

You can override in this fashion using:

```
  devise_for :administrator, controllers: {
      sessions: 'administrators/sessions',
      registrations: 'administrators/registrations',
      passwords: 'administrators/passwords',
      invitations: 'administrators/invitations' ### <== NOTE THIS
  },
             path_names: {
                 sign_in: 'login',
                 sign_out: 'logout',
                 registration: 'register'
             },
             path: 'administrators' ### <== NOTE THIS
```

Just fixed this issue on my setup.

ENjoy.